# alphabetizing error on glossary in tufte-book

Tags: glossary

I'm using `tufte-book` under TeXShop 3.96 on a Mac and the following relevant code:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{terminus ante quem}{
    name={terminus ante quem},
    description={(from Latin, \lq\lq term before which\rq\rq ) the latest possible time consistent with some event, such as the lastest possible date by which a particular artwork could have been executed.  (See also \lq\lq terminus post quem\rq\rq )}
}

\newglossaryentry{terminus post quem}{
    name={terminus post quem},
    description={(from Latin, \lq\lq term after which\rq\rq ) the earliest possible time consistent with some event, such as the earliest possible date by which a particular artwork could have been executed.  (See also \lq\lq terminus ante quem\rq\rq )}
}
\begin{document}

xxx \gls{terminus ante quem}

xxx \gls{terminus post quem}

\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the alphabetization is reversed (just on these two entries):

[image]

Any suggestions on how to retain proper alphabetization?  Even artificially switching the order of entries in the glossary list does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully traced what the package is doing, but you can help it with a sort key.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{terminus ante quem}{
    sort=terminusantequem,
    name={terminus ante quem},
    description={(from Latin, \lq\lq term before which\rq\rq ) the latest possible time consistent with some event, such as the lastest possible date by which a particular artwork could have been executed.  (See also \lq\lq terminus post quem\rq\rq )}
}

\newglossaryentry{terminus post quem}{
    sort=terminuspostquem,
    name={terminus post quem},
    description={(from Latin, \lq\lq term after which\rq\rq ) the earliest possible time consistent with some event, such as the earliest possible date by which a particular artwork could have been executed.  (See also \lq\lq terminus ante quem\rq\rq )}
}
\begin{document}

xxx \gls{terminus ante quem}

xxx \gls{terminus post quem}

\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh *perfect*!  Thanks so much.  (+1 and a hearty accept).  (Wow... 673k reputation.  Clearly!)