Unnecessary content in Glossary
I could see some of the uncalled names that have the 'see=' in the syntax, like lava in the example below are displayed in the glossary. How do I sort this issue? Thank you in advance
An example of the syntax:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[postdot]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{amsha}
{
    sort=aMsha,
    name={\textit{aṁśa}},
    description={Degree in arc units}
}

\newglossaryentry{lava}
{
    sort=lava,
    name={\textit{lava}},
    description={},
    see={amsha}
}

%
\begin{document}
zxxxx 
%\gls{amsha}
%if \gls{lava}

\printglossary[title=Glossary]

\end{document}
%

Output:


Please add a meaningful MWE here and focus on a single problem.
Don't just link to external pages containing the LaTeX code or parts of it.
External links can become invalid or inaccessible, and the question could lose any value to future visitors.

For your second question about sorting see, e.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653209/277964

Thank you.. The Second part of the question got resolved. Please let me know about the first part.. Why without calling, the items are appearing in the glossary?

Sorry, as long as you ignore my request in my first comment, I even do not have a chance to answer this. See also the link in that comment.

This is not the default behaviour, so it is caused by some code you've not shared.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.
